# Find max value from alphanumeric string on the basis of its numeric value in db2 database

Tags: database, db2

Actually I have data in my column like this-- abc1,abc2,..,abc50,pqr1,pqr2,...,pqr120,xyz1,xyz2,...,xyz200‌​.Now i want to get max value for having prefix xyz.So for this purpose i used this query --`

```
select MAX(fieldName) from table where fieldName like 'xyz%'
```

This query was returning result as xyz99 as max but Expected result should be xyz200 as max..Now i want to know how to use 'like' query in MAX function to get desired output.OR is there any way to find out max value on the basis of its numeric value.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle or DB2? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I am using db2 database.

Comment: Then you can remove the MySQL and Oracle tags.

Comment: Do you have any answer for my question?

Comment: The problem is that you're storing numeric values as character data. The string '99' is higher that '200'. Either separate the xyz from the 200 into two columns in the table, or in the select.

Comment: I know the concept behind this.But how it can be possible to get desired o/p. If you know, send the query.

Comment: Always 3 leading letters, and then the number?

Comment: yes exactly....3 leading letters then number

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table
where substring(fieldName,3,length(fieldName)-3) = 
(select max(substring(fieldName,3,length(fieldName)-3))  
from table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT max(CAST(substring(fieldName,4) AS UNSIGNED)) AS maxVal
FROM `table`
WHERE fieldName LIKE 'xyz%'
```

Comment: I am getting this below error-

THE DATA TYPE, LENGTH, OR VALUE OF ARGUMENT 1 OF SUBSTRING IS INVALID SQL Code: -171, SQL State: 42815

Comment: Can you write here your query? are you using mysql ?

Comment: I am using db2. See this query
SELECT max(CAST(substring(ID,4) AS UNSIGNED)) AS maxVal FROM table WHERE ID LIKE 'xyz%';
In this what is the use of 4?

Comment: My Query is for MySQL

Comment: No, I do not have any idea

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUBSTR()` to separate the *xxxnnn* values into a character part and an integer part. `Cast` the integer part of the string to an integer. `Order by` these two parts separately - descending. Use `FETCH FIRST` to pick the max value!

```
select fieldName
from table
where fieldName like 'xyz%'
order by substr(fieldName,1,3) desc,
         cast(substr(fieldName,4) as integer) desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

Comment: I am getting this error--

THE VALUE OF A STRING ARGUMENT WAS NOT ACCEPTABLE TO THE SYSIBM.INTEGER FUNCTION SQL Code: -420, SQL State: 22018

Comment: Can you try `select fieldName, substr(fieldName,1,3), substr(fieldName,4) from table where fieldName like 'xyz%'`? Any non-integers in the third column?

Comment: Thank you so much....your answer give me the correct way to get desired output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Select concat('XYZ', max(regexp_replace(fieldName, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') ::int)) from table;
```

If you want to extract only integer value from alphanumeric field, you can simply use -

```
Select regexp_replace(fieldName, '[^0-9]', '', 'g') ::int) from table;
```